# Segmentation fault after launch rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm, factory-bot, rspec-rails, ruby-1.9.3

We're working in a RoR app (Ruby v. 1.9.3, RoR v. 3.2.12, rvm v. 1.8.14) and when we launch a rspec test, we obtain the following crash (I can't copy here, it's too long):

https://gist.github.com/pabloDon/5361689

If we try to launch it many times, finally we can launch it (of course, with no source code changes).

This problem appears with all specs, so I think that our code is not the problem. If it helps, here is the last test that crash:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admin::PedidosController do

  describe "GET 'index'" do
    [.. other specs...]

    it "populates an array of carts" do
      category = FactoryGirl.create :category, category_id: nil
      product = FactoryGirl.create :product, category_id: category.id
      cart = FactoryGirl.create :cart      
      cart_product = FactoryGirl.create :cart_product, product_id:product.id, cart_id: cart.id                      

      get 'index'                               
      assigns(:orders).should eq([cart])        

    end
  end

    [.. other specs...]

end
```

If you need more code and/or logs, just say it! :)
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. try `rvm get head; rvm reinstall 1.9.3` - follow the instructions, it possibly can solve problems with libraries as there is `Psych` in the stack which uses `libyaml`.
2. try updating your application to new ruby `rvm get head; rvm use --install 2.0.0`

If the problem still persists on `2.0.0` then try to isolate it to smallest possible example and report to https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/

Comment: We've done it and It didn't work :(. We'll report it to Ruby comm.